# How to offset flex item?

Tags: css, flexbox, margin, grid-system

I'm developing a pure flexbox grid framework called [flexboxes](https://github.com/ryanve/flexboxes). I'm looking to implement a way to offset flex items by a particular number of grid columns in any `flex-direction`. [This is possible with percentage margin but can it be done in a simpler way using flex properties?](https://codepen.io/ryanve/pen/jmjMoJ) With what's available in [flexboxes@0.4.0](https://github.com/ryanve/flexboxes/tree/v0.4.0)?  I'd rather not implement margin classes this way because doing to would seemingly require adding classes for all 4 directions to accommodate all `flex-direction` values.

Comment: Flexbox itself does not have properties of its own for offset. A tip would be to check how Bootstrap did with their flexbox version.

Comment: Btw, there is no such display value as `display: flex-item`

Comment: Margin it is https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/flexbox-justified-and-offsetstaggered/

Comment: @LGSon Nice catch about display—thanks :)